# mongoose . is it possible to delete if exist and insert if not in one operation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a like module that going to be used ***alot*** ! users going to send like request if object liked or not.

> (like and unlike is calling the same REST endpoint)

i can do `findByIdAndRemove` and check if its deleted anything and if not , create the LIKE .

i can `findOne` the LIKE and delete if exist and create if not .

but this way is most likly two operations sent to database . ( some cases 1 operation ).

what im asking is : is it possible to do this in one operation ?

***LikeSchema fields : ***

`_id`
`_object`
`_user`
`createdAt`

> Update #1 : 
>   my like model as requested :

```
const likeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        require: true
    },
    _entity: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        require: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['path', 'stage', 'step', 'task', 'user']
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    }
});

likeSchema.virtual('user', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: '_user',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Like', likeSchema);
```

> Update 2 : Input parameters

ps: user id add base on its token .

```
{
    "_entity" : "5d725a1b7b292f5f8ceff788",
    "type" : "path"
}
```

Comment: I cannot really judge this, but you might reconsider providing seperate endpoints for like and unlike, or specifying which should be done by some kind of parameter. You would avoid your problem that way and at the same time, you would guard yourself against UI and REST API being out of sync. Imagine a user clicking "Like", because the UI thinks that the item is currently not liked, but effectively the user would be unliking the item because the current displayed state is incorrect.

Comment: @Dennis thanks for your reply . initially i wrote two endpoint and ask the front-end to use it this way . but they insist on having one action on the LIKE Button on the Application using it . im against it but i have to do the job. the least i can do is not exhaust the database .

Comment: Can you add your schema as code?

Comment: @SuleymanSah my model as requested . sry for delay . time difference :)

Comment: And what are the inputs-parameters to your api when liked and unliked?

Comment: @SuleymanSah here is the input parameters . thanks for reply

Comment: Dont we need user info when a like happens?

Comment: @SuleymanSah   doing the user stuff on token and on the business logic of controller .

Comment: @SuleymanSah Like and Unlike both happens with the same input . i need to handle it . if it exist , delete it . and if not , create it

Comment: But how will we understand which used liked with this input?

Comment: @SuleymanSah if there is a record in this collection for specific entity . its a LIKE . count of them = LIKES , i don`t know if i get your question right .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205647/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-hamid-salari).